# TV broadcast with only speech

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that would refer to TV-series which is plain voice. To be exact, there's someone reading you a book, no any kind of video even though it is broadcast through TV. Would "narrated TV-series" be wrong?

EDIT: asking this since in my first language we have a special word for this. A TV-series would be either "TV-ohjelma" or "TV-sarja", and a TV-series like I described "puheohjelma" (with or without the TV prefix).

EDIT2: If I use "radio", people will assume the wrong type of device used to transmit the speech.

Comment: I would think since basically what you're describing is *radio*, you'd need to explicitly state that the broadcast would be completely imageless.

Comment: ggg, how about "audio TV-series" or even "audio series" whitout using "TV"? It is clear that an "audio series" is not a thing we use to talk about the programmes transmitted via radio.

Comment: You say that "If I use 'radio', people will assume the wrong type of device used to transmit the speech". Does that matter. In the UK, we can receive and listen to radio stations using a TV set.

Comment: There's no single word for such a concept in English. You'd need to explicitly describe it as, say, *an audio-only tv broadcast* to avoid being misunderstood.

Comment: Are you thinking something up or have you experienced this? Either there is a inside technical term for it (that TV producers use) or...

Comment: your TV monitor is broken.

Comment: "There's someone reading a book" Do we see this person reading a book? (from your description you said there "no kind of video" which I'm going to interpret as there being no 'film' or actors involved)

Comment: I might say "audio-only TV" ... but that would allow for music and other sounds as well as speech.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are talking about a broadcast that is being distributed over the frequencies used by television, even though there is no video content, and not those frequencies used by radio or the distribution over an internet connection.

If this is so, the phrase *TV-frequency audio* would seen to cover what you are trying to convey.

In the US, there are some radio units (sound only) that receive *TV-audio*.

The phrase *narrated TV-series* would be ambiguous, because it could encompass a TV program that includes a visual image of someone reading, which I do not think you intend.

Answer (score 0):

‘Narrated TV series’ would only mean a TV series where the action is narrated, possibly in addition to being acted out as usual.

As you say it, it seems someone’s image will actually appear reading the book.  So I would go for a description on the lines of a ‘book reading TV series’.  As there is precedent for that in social meetings and on theatre, where a text is often read dramatically even if is is not enacted in scenes, if it is the case where there will be several readers, ‘dramatic reading TV series’ would even be better, but it would fit also the situation where a sole reader is able to dramaticise his reading with emphasis, voice alterations &c.

So I would go for ‘dramatic reading’.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of a thing called "Spoken Word Teleseries" although I never actually watched it myself.

I assume the title implies it is a tele-series using the art of Spoken Word Poetry.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoken_word

Relevant?